# Matplotlib Histogram Alignment

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

```
def vs_time(data): #MUBASHWER, histogram
    clf()
    hist(data.keys(), bins = 12, weights = data.values())
    xticks(arange(0,24,2))
    xlabel('Time')
    ylabel('Number of fatalities')
    title('Number of Fatalities vs Time')
    webshow('vs_time.png')
```

histogram:[image]

I want the hours in x-axis to be on the left edge of each bar. But they are neither at the centre, nor at any edge. Please help. The problem could be solved if the histogram could be shirted without altering the axis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is clearly because the bin edges of your resulting histogram are not just even numbers 0,2,4....22.

To get the desired result, simply make use of the `bins=` argument and, i.e., :

```
plt.hist(YOUR_DATA,bins=arange(0,24,2)) #for bin edge 0,2,4...,22, as in your figure.
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. If it's ok, could you please explain why this is the case?

Comment: Sure, when you don't specify `bins`, the edges will be determined automatically; when you specify `bins` by an `int`, the edges will be determined by how the data is distributed. Either case, there is no guarantee that the edges will fall right on the exact values that you wanted. Therefore, the straight way is to specify `bins` to a `array` containing the edges.